# Google Places Api in Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-places-api, static-libraries

I start whit a cross-platform project where i need to use Google Places Api and other but unfortunately i don't find a library for use in Xamarin.Forms.
By the way i can use web service api for get json and create my objects, now i think to create a very small library for Xamarin.Forms and i have few questions:

- I can create objects based on json and web service api of Google Places but i don't know if this is a good idea, now i use **json2csharp** for map the json and create class but if google change a name of variable or add other my creation object failed. This is a good practice?
- In terms of performance is good to use web service for create objects and use in xamarin.forms project?
- This is a good idea for create a library which does not exist? I don't know the structure of this type of library

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use any library to map JSON. If Google changes a name of a variable a lot of people will have problems. So if they decide to do that, most likely they will do a different API and left current untouched.

2) Yes, the web request by itself is a heavy operation. There is a little difference in where you store it.

3) There are a lot of them for .Net. For example: https://github.com/linguanostra/GoogleMapsAPI.NET

The thing is that this API is like a library by itself. Theoretically, you can write a wrapper around them, but the thing is that would it be flexible enough to use it as a library? But that on you to decide. It's always fun to create small things and share them with a world (if you plan to open source it).